# ElasticSearch: unable to resolve class org.joda.time.Period

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using this script in order to get the time difference between two fields:

```
new org.joda.time.Period(doc[firstDateField].date, doc[secondDateField].date).getHours();
```

The problem is ES is telling me that:

```
bbd8b73ce0b0dd070d07e63f11dcdad4fa12121d: 1: unable to resolve class org.joda.time.Period
Nov 04 10:27:21 core-01 docker[3876]:  @ line 1, column 1.
Nov 04 10:27:21 core-01 docker[3876]:    new Period(doc[firstDateField].date, doc[secondDateField].date).getHours();
Nov 04 10:27:21 core-01 docker[3876]:    ^
```

Comment: I'm closing this question because this specific issue is already being handled in the referenced question.

Comment: I've thought that would be better to open a new post since maybe the post you get reference has been a bit fuzzy. Sorry.